macbook terminal tab complete python module
On my old MacBookPro, I was able to tab-complete python modules on Terminal...
but now, as soon as theres a "dot" in the path, Terminal can no longer tab-complete 
(so basically only tab-completes at the "ls" level). How to bring it back? Thank you!
Example:
cwd/
├── basic.py
└── tools
    ├── some_script.py
    ├── another_script.py
    └── third_script.py

What I want on Terminal:

I type: python -m tools.so

lolo@lolo cwd % python -m tools.so

I click TAB (once or twice, i don't care)

lolo@lolo cwd % python -m tools.some_script

tab-completed me_script for me

Python: 3.11.9
MacBookPro: Late 2023, Sonoma 14.1.1
I tried searching, but I think I don't know all the correct terminologies, so I was unable to get any meaningful or similar search results.

what is your shell? I'm not sure if this is always accurate, but what does echo $SHELL give you?

@juanpa.arrivillaga /bin/zsh

Could you try the tab-complete using / instead of the ..
So in your example it would be

You type: python -m tools.so

lolo@lolo cwd % python -m tools/so

You click TAB (once or twice)

lolo@lolo cwd % python -m tools/some_script
I always use a slash and it works perfectly for me.
To give you some context, even I am on a MacbookPro with simlar configurations as you.

using the -m flag? are you sure?
